# WikiJS API retrieve image from page

Tags: javascript, json, graphql

I'm trying to create a query string in GraphQL (provided by Wiki JS) where I can retrieve page data. I'm hoping to be able to retrieve the first image on the page, but I cannot seem to find this anywhere in the documentation.

```
query {
  pages {
    list {
       id
       title
       description
       path
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know a way to retrieve the url of the first image on a Wiki JS page?

Answer (score -1):

List all the pages with your query then execute the following query:

```js
{
  pages {
    single (id:1) {
      content
    }
  }
}
```